# Pyspark: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (double) => double)

Tags: pyspark

I have a column which I'm converting to double from string but I get the below error.

```
An error occurred while calling o2564.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 619.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 619.0  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (double) => double)

train_with_summary.select('cd_val').show(10)
+-------------------+
|       cd_val      |
+-------------------+
|                  1|
|                  9|
|                  9|
|                  0|
|                  1|
|                  3|
|                  3|
|                  0|
|                  1|
|                  2|
+-------------------+

bucket_cols = ['cd_val']
for bucket_col in bucket_cols:
    train_with_summary = train_with_summary.withColumn(bucket_col,train_with_summary[bucket_col].cast(DoubleType()))
    bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[-float("inf"),4,9,14,19],inputCol=bucket_col,outputCol=bucket_col+"_buckets")
    train_with_summary = bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("keep").transform(train_with_summary)
    print(bucket_col)

print(train_with_summary.select([bucket_col,bucket_col+'_buckets']).show(10))
```

The erorr was at the last line and there were no Null values in the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself, The error is because it is trying to convert from double to double type itself.

Since I ran the code twice, the initial run converted the column.